# Rename vars with numeric names

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

Say I have a dataframe with variables that have numeric names that I want to rename by adding character prefixes.

```
country <- c("country","US","France")
var1  <- c(234234,234234,1233124)
var2  <- c(34534,25674,123124)

df <- data.frame(country,var1,var2) %>% rename('2021' = var1,'2022' = var2)
```

| Country | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| country | 234234 | 34534 |
| US | 234234 | 25674 |
| France | 1233124 | 123124 |

Example table is weird, sorry. My attempt using rename_if:

```
df_clean <- df %>%
  rename_if(startsWith(names(.),"20"), ~paste0("ben",.))
```

I get variable names that have quotes around the years.

| Country | ben'2021' | ben'2022' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| country | 234234 | 34534 |
| US | 234234 | 25674 |
| France | 1233124 | 123124 |

I want:

| Country | ben2021 | ben2022 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| country | 234234 | 34534 |
| US | 234234 | 25674 |
| France | 1233124 | 123124 |

I'd appreciate any help with the rename. Sorry if formatting isn't right and if I missed the answer in my search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `rename_with` instead of the superseded `rename_if` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df_clean <- df %>%
  rename_with(~ paste0("ben", .), starts_with("20"))

df_clean
#>   country ben2021 ben2022
#> 1 country  234234   34534
#> 2      US  234234   25674
#> 3  France 1233124  123124
```